# Reorder columns and rows of Holoviews Heatmap based on similarity measure (e.g. cosine similarity etc.)

Tags: sorting, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap, holoviews

I was surprised that no one seems to have asked this before.

Assuming I have a pandas dataframe (random example), I can get a heatmap with Holoviews and Bokeh renderer:

```py
rownames = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,size=(20, len(rownames))), columns=list(rownames))
hv.HeatMap({'x': df.columns, 'y': df.index, 'z': df}, 
           kdims=[('x', 'Col Categories'), ('y', 'Row Categories')], 
           vdims='z').opts(cmap="viridis", width=520, height=520)
```

[image]

The data (x and y) is categorical, therefore the initial order of rows or columns is unimportant. I wanted to sort rows/columns based on some similarity measure.

One way is to use seaborn clustermap:

```py
heatmap_sns = sns.clustermap(df, metric="cosine", standard_scale=1, method="ward", cmap="viridis")
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Columns and rows have been ordered according to similarity (in this case, cosine based on dot product; others are available such as 'correlation' etc.).

However, I want to display the clustermap in Holoviews. How do I update ordering of the original dataframe from the seaborn matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much cleaner approach to Alex's answer (i.e. that was the accepted answer earlier) is to use the `data2d` property of the returned object from `sns.clustermap()` function. This property contains the reordered data (i.e. the data after clustering). So:

```
df_ro = heatmap_sns.data2d
```

replaces all the following lines:

```
# get col and row names by ID
colname_list = [df.columns[col_id] for col_id in 
heatmap_sns.dendrogram_col.reordered_ind]
rowname_list = [df.index[row_id] for row_id in 
heatmap_sns.dendrogram_row.reordered_ind]
# update dataframe
df_ro = df.reindex(rowname_list)
df_ro = df_ro[colname_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to access the indices of reordered columns/rows from the seaborn clustermap using:

```py
> print(f'rows: {heatmap_sns.dendrogram_row.reordered_ind}')
> print(f'columns: {heatmap_sns.dendrogram_col.reordered_ind}')
rows: [5, 0, 13, 2, 18, 7, 4, 16, 12, 19, 14, 15, 10, 3, 8, 6, 17, 11, 1, 9]
columns: [7, 1, 10, 5, 9, 0, 8, 13, 2, 6, 14, 3, 4, 11, 12]
```

To update row/column order of the original dataframe:

```py
# get col and row names by ID
colname_list = [df.columns[col_id] for col_id in heatmap_sns.dendrogram_col.reordered_ind]
rowname_list = [df.index[row_id] for row_id in heatmap_sns.dendrogram_row.reordered_ind]
# update dataframe
df_ro = df.reindex(rowname_list)
df_ro = df_ro[colname_list]
```

I've done it here by first getting the names, perhaps there's even a direct way to update columns/rows by indices.

```py
hv.HeatMap({'x': df_ro.columns, 'y': df_ro.index, 'z': df_ro}, 
           kdims=[('x', 'Col Categories'), ('y', 'Row Categories')], 
           vdims='z').opts(cmap="viridis", width=520, height=520)
```

Since I have used random data, there's little order in the categories, but still the picture looks a little less noisy. Note that holoviews/df y axis is simply inverse compared to the seaborn clustermap-matrix, that's why the graphic looks flipped.

[image]